# Validate First and Last name (not using regular expression)

Tags: javascript

I need to validate user input of first and last name in the one input box. I have to make sure they only use letters and no other characters and is in uppercase or lowercase ex.. John Smith. I can find a lot of ways to do this using regular expressions, but the task has specifically asked that no regular expressions be used.

Even if someone to point me to where I can find this information myself.

Thanks

Comment: You are going to make Mrs. O'Doule upset. And if not her, then a lot of other people. (This is one of those cases where I urge pushback and softer constraints.)

Comment: Please post your code you got so far so we can help.

Comment: Only letters? What about Mr. O'Reilly? Or Ms. Smyth-Jones?

Comment: you could restrict the user from entering non alphabets..will that do?

Comment: Split input using space...!

Comment: @user2246674   Yes I understand that in a normal case, you would not restrict so much but it is the way I need to do it for uni...

Comment: @SonyaHancock I misread the bit about "no regular expression" - in that case, see "loops" in the text book and get this assignment over with. JavaScript strings can be accessed by index, just like an array. `"hello"[0]"` results in `"h"`. Then it can be observed that strings are ordered, such that `"a" < "b" < .. "z"` (and the same goes for the upper-case versions, but it is an *ordinal* ordering, not an alphabetical ordering).

Comment: @user2246674 Yes one would think that we have covered it in our studies, and perhaps we have and I am just having a blank. I am going back through everything we have covered to refresh my memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just check each letter to see if it's valid.  So you create an array of valid characters, then make sure each character is in that array.

```
function validate_name(name) {
  var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  alphabet = alphabet + ' ' + alphabet.toUpperCase();
  alphabet = alphabet.split(''); //turn it into an array of letters.
  for (i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
    if (!~alphabet.indexOf(name.charAt(i)) { //!~ just turns -1 into true
       return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that, given the question, it is best to keep the solution simple.

Note this observations:

1. A string can be indexed like an array and has a length like an array. Thus, a string can be looped like an array.
2. Strings are lexically ordered. That is, `"a" < "b"` and `"A" < "B"` are both true.
3. String.toLower can translate `"A"` to `"a"`

Then we can start a basic C-style approach:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inp.lenth; i++) {
   var ch = inp[ch];
   if (ch == " ") ..              // is space
   if (ch >= "a" && ch <= "z") .. // lowercase English letter
   ..
```

Of course, the problem may be more than simply ensuring that the letters are all in { a-z, A-Z, space}. Consider these inputs - are they valid?

- "John  Doe"
- "JohnDoe"
- " John "

Comment: Yes John Doe is correct, the other two are not.... so i have to make it that both names need to be imputed and separated by space... and yes I am still trying to get my head around the javascript so simple solutions sounds good lol thanks